# form control jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this form, take from site , i have add input and now not work

I just have to figure out what 's wrong with the control jQuery

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <h3><strong>1.</strong> <span>Informazioni personali</span></h3>







            </div><!-- /.span4 -->





            <div class="span4">

                <h3><strong>3.</strong> <span>Upload Foto</span></h3>

                <div class="fileupload fileupload-new control-group" data-provides="fileupload">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputPropertyPrice">
                        Image files
                    </label>

                    <div class="input-append">
                        <div class="uneditable-input">
                            <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i>
                            <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
                        </div>
                                            <span class="btn btn-file">
                                                <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
                                                <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
                                                <input type="file"  name="file" id="file" />
                                            </span>
                        <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
                    </div><!-- /.input-append -->
                </div><!-- .fileupload -->
```

I can not put all the above code so I made ​​a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exolon82/2vhsv5zw/).

do you think the tag upload is right? Where do I upload the file I wrote well?

how can I add an upload that takes only .jpg ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple typos in the code:

- `|| bagni == ||` should be  `|| bagni == "" ||`
- `!emailReg.test(email)` should be `!emailReg.test(email1)`

[Fined JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vhsv5zw/1/)

Try and use the developer console before asking a question on SO.